# Convert.ToInt32 does not take the a zero ( 0 ) as a starting integer

Tags: c#

I have a question or actually two regarding the 
`Convert.ToInt32` function or `Int32.Parse`.

It seems when I use `Int32.Parse("06487965")` or the other function it just seems to lose the `0`.
So the output will be `"6487965"`.

My questions:

1. Why is that exactly ?
2. How can I solve this without getting into crazy hacks ?

Comment: what is the problem? 0 at the beginning doesn't count as a digit

Comment: Numbers do not have leading zeros. If they did what would be the difference between 1 apple and 01 apple?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko. What about 01 apple and 001 apple? Does it work only with apples? How can I solve it?

Comment: I think you are confused Shinji. I would rather see it strip the leading zeros then keep them because then it wouldn't be a valid Int32 if it kept the leading zeros. The leading zero is only for formatting. Some formats have leading zeros for fixed length fields. You can usually store it however you want, but when it comes time to display to the user or write it back out, you normally want to restore the original zero padding so it appears to maintain the original formatting. How you handle it underneath though is usually a different story.

Comment: My problem was that I just need to keep all of my digits. These numbers represent an id.  Some of those start with a zero other do not that is why I wanted to just keep everything.However your answers are much appreciated!

Comment: @Shinji - If you're numbers are id's then you shouldn't be converting them to Int32 in the first place.  They should remain strings.  Will you be doing any calculations with your id's?  That seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leading 0's aren't represented when you `ToString` an `int` by default. You want to pass a format like `"00000000"`.

```
int value =  Int32.Parse("06487965");
string stringAgain = value.ToString("000000000");
```

Answer (score 5):

Leading-zeroes are purely a formatting idiom.  An actual *number* has no leading zeroes as they make no sense and are superfluous.

You don't really have anything to solve, BUT, if you want to display the number at a later point with a leading zero, then you can use string formatting to achieve this.

```
int myNum = 6487965;
string formatted = string.Format("{0:00000000}", myNum);
```

Comment: Maybe he should start by storing it as a string, if that leading 0 is relevant to him, it doesnt seem to be typed correctly in the first place.

Comment: @squelos, I can only see it being relevant for string comparison purposes such as order numbers, invoices numbers etc.  If that's what they are, then you are perhaps right - there is no need to convert to an integer at all unless one wants to find the "next invoice" number, but then we're in a whole new realm.  I think, perhaps, the OP should elaborate a bit.

Comment: Yes, he surely should elaborate. It is possible that it should be an int, but that Exceptionnaly, he wants to format it with a leading 0. But he might also be wrong on the data type he is using.

Answer (score 3):

1. Leading zeroes do not make sense mathematically
2. You can't have leading zeroes in an integer, if you must have leading zeroes best way is to keep your variable as string.

Answer (score 2):

Because in that form, the leading `0`, or `0`s is/are nonsensical and redundant.

It can become useful in terms of formatting, for visual representation when you know how it should be formatted, but otherwise it is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

Leading zeroes are meaningless when converting to a numeric type like Int32 - it only cares about the actual numeric value represented by the string you're converting from, which is the same regardless of the number of zeroes stuck on the front.

If later on in your program you want to convert your Int32 back to a string or output it to your user then at that point you need to do some formatting to get the number of leading zeroes you want.  The MSDN article ["How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx) would be a good place to start with that.

Answer (score 0):

integer 06487965 equals to integer 6487965

Answer (score 0):

because, nobody uses pading, here is it:

```
int intValue =  Int32.Parse("06487965");
string stringAgain = intValue.ToString().PadLeft(9, '0');
```